# Let $σ$ be the relation on $R×R$ in which $(a,b) σ (x,y)$ if and only if $a ≤ x$ and $b ≤ y$. Prove that $σ$ is a partial order relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I can prove it is reflexive and transitive but I cannot prove that it is antisymmetric. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(a,b) \sigma (x,y) \implies a \leq x \wedge b \leq y$$

$$(x,y) \sigma (a,b) \implies x \leq a \wedge y \leq b$$

If $a \leq x$ and $x \leq a$ what can you conclude?

what about $b\leq y$ and $y \leq b$?

Comment: Nice answer, btw (already upvoted, yesterday)....  Great balance: I call answers like this good examples of the  "[Goldilock's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle)": not too much, not too little, but just right!